# map probabilities and classes (multiclass) to dataframe most efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have trained an xgboost nulticlass classifier.
I want predictions for the class and for the probabilities

Let's say I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

result = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4], 'Pred class': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']})
predictions = np.array([[0.2, 0.3, 0.5],
                        [0.1, 0.5, 0.4], 
                        [0.7, 0.2, 0.1],
                        [0.4, 0.2, 0.6]])
```

I am finding the indices of the maximum probabilities:

```
max_probs = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
```

and I am creating a list with the maximum probabilities in each class:

```
res = []
for idx, (el, el2) in enumerate(zip(predictions, max_probs)):
    res.append(predictions[idx, max_probs[idx] ] * 100)
```

Then, I add the result to original dataframe:

```
result['probs'] = res
```

and I have:

```
  id Pred class  probs
  1          a   50.0
  2          b   50.0
  3          c   70.0
  4          c   60.0
```

Which is most efficient way to do this for a larger dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using Pandas [max](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```py
result["probs"] = pd.DataFrame(predictions).max(axis=1) * 100
```

```py
print(result)
# Output
   id Pred class  probs
0   1          a   50.0
1   2          b   50.0
2   3          c   70.0
3   4          c   60.0
```